# PDP Controller not Transmitting Mic Audio

Tags: controllers

My last controller from PDP played their terrifying sound that killed my Mic in my headset. I returned both my Headset *HyperX Cloud II* and my Controller *PDP Afterglow Wired Controller*

I now have the PDP Midnight Blue Wired Controller and a new headset. I plugged in my Controller and headset and they both worked. 
I then had to leave for around 30 or so minutes. I signed out of my xbox but didnt power it off. when i came back and signed in I joined a party to find that no one could hear me. I had my Mic Monitoring turned on and I can hear myself but it wont show me talking.

I looked up and it said in some cases people factory reset their controller and it worked. I reset my controller around 8 times and still nothing

Does anyone know how to correct this issue, or am I stuck with this piece of junk?

((New)) I also kept spamming Y to mute my mic and I also spammed the Button below the right stick and it showed for a brief moment that my mic transmitted audio.